# How to pass/set enivronment varialbes in pytest?

Tags: python, pytest, fastapi

I have a fast api app, (sample code below ), in my main.py file . i have some environment variables that i read at runtime. i have set up a test as well with pytest for this in my test folder. How can i set the environment variable , while running the test, in this case some_env_var.

I want to set this to certain value before running the test.
also, going through some examples based on pytest, moto library to mock aws services . i have set up a conftest.py file , with fake aws credentials . but when i run this. i always get "unable to locate credentials" . what is the correct set up for this.

main.py

```
from fastapi import APIRouter
import boto3
app = FastAPI()

some_env_var = os.get("some_var")

s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
@app.get("/posts")
def list_posts():
    //call a database to records 
     records = db_service.get(....

    // upload a results to s3 bucket  
   s3_client.upload(...
   ....
```

test folder -

- conftest.py
- test_main.py

test_main.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient

app = FastAPI()

test_client = TestClient(app)

def test_list_posts():    
   response = test_client.posts("/posts")    
   assert response.status_code == 200   
   ...
```

conftest.py

```
import boto3
import os
import pytest

from moto import mock_s3

@pytest.fixture
def aws_credentials():
    """Mocked AWS Credentials for moto."""
    os.environ["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"] = "testing"
    os.environ["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"] = "testing"
    os.environ["AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN"] = "testing"
    os.environ["AWS_SESSION_TOKEN"] = "testing"
```

Comment: where are you using `mock_s3`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `monkeypatch` to set the environment variables

```
@pytest.fixture
def aws_credentials(monkeypatch):
    """Mocked AWS Credentials for moto."""
    monkeypatch.setenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID", "testing")
    monkeypatch.setenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY", "testing")
    monkeypatch.setenv("AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN", "testing")
    monkeypatch.setenv("AWS_SESSION_TOKEN", "testing")
```

All modifications will be undone after the requesting test function or fixture has finished.

Comment: This will work unless you import one of the app files in `conftest.py` (which might be done to create some fixtures).

Comment: @M.O. - thanks . i didn't see that in any of the example i saw online . can you point me to an example

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [pytest-env](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-env/), which is built to do exactly this.

Comment: pyenv-test won't allow you to add/remove variables dynamically, so you may end up needing monkeypatch anyway